# C - Why this expression *q = *(q + 1) produced error when dealing with the string?

Tags: c

```
void delchar(char *s, char c){
  char *p, *q = NULL;
  for(p = s;*p != '\0'; p++){
    if(*p == c){
        q = p;
        do{
            *q = *(q + 1);
            q++;
        }while(*q != '\0');
    }
 }
}
```

I wanted to use this code to delete a specific letter in a string, so I created a pointer p to scan the string, create another pointer q to move the elements behind that specific letter and cover it. But it turned out that the expression *q = *(q + 1) which is used to move and cover made error"Program received a signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault".I just don't know the reason on it.

Comment: Step through the code, line by line, in a debugger, while monitoring the contents of all variables and how they change.

Comment: Cannot reproduce the problem. Show a complete self contained example please that reproduces the problem please.

Comment: @2501, segfaults are often undefined behaviour, so in your case it might work anyway.

Comment: I agree with @2501, code of this function seems to be OK. We need to see how it is called. Problem could be it is called to update a char array missing the leading `\0` or it could be trying to update an array which cannot be.

Comment: Is the string you are calling this on (`*s`) perhaps a constant in the code, like `char *s = "1234567890"` ? In that case, the segfault is caused because you may not write in the code section.

Comment: Actually I was wrong, there is a flaw in the algorithm, see my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Even though you won't get a segmentation fault because of that, there is a flaw in your algorithm. You advance your `p` cursor even if you deleted a char.

Use a `while` instead of a `for`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void delchar(char *s, char c)
{
    char *p, *q = NULL;

    p = s;
    while (*p != '\0')
    {
        if (*p == c)
        {
            q = p;
            do {
                *q = *(q + 1);
                q++;
            } while(*q != '\0');
        }
        else
            p++; // Advance cursor only if no character was deleted
    }
}

int main()
{
    char str[1024];
    strcpy(str, "Yes or  no?");
    delchar(str, ' ');
    printf("%s\n", str);

    return 0;
}
```

output:

> Yesorno?

A reason why you could get a segmentation fault is because trying to update an string literal. String literals are not done to be modified. They are not the same at all than an array of char. The main difference is you cannot overwrite their content.

```
int main()
{
    char *str = "to to"; // string literal
    delchar(str, ' '); // segmentation fault

    char array[] = "to to"; // array of char
    delchar(array, ' '); // no segmentation fault
    printf("%s\n", str);

    return 0;
}
```

You could duplicate your string with `strcpy()` the same way I do above, or you can use an array of chars instead of a string literal.

Comment: Yes that was a flaw in the algorithm, but the code itself was still defined. It just didn't erase properly. This question should have been handled differently, it should be closed, because any answer is just guesswork.

Comment: @2501 As I said, try `delchar(str, '?');` with my `main()` and the question's code and you could get a segfault.

Comment: That is not correct. I have written down my reasoning on the comments of another answer, but it was deleted by the owner. You can step through the code if you don't believe me. Anyhow the only way OP's code would cause ub is if the argument c was the null terminator.

Comment: @2501 After thinking twice you are right, we can't get a segfault because we can skip the end of the string but not the original `\0` which is still there, so the seg fault the OP get should be due to another reason.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Exactly, the error showed when I put a intern string into this function, when i changed it into a "char" array there was no error appeared again.I thought the reason is that intern string is read-only, but I am still wondering that why intern string just can be read? I learned that if I create a intern string with array, the element can be updated, but if i create it with a pointer, it will make error. What is the reason?????

Comment: @Stephen.W I updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

There is a reason why this can happen: when you try to write in strings that are in the code section of your program (instead of on stack or heap).

Calling the code like this (the data is in the (readonly) code section):

```
char *s = "1234567890";
delchar(s, '5');
```

will segfault, but this (the data is on the heap):

```
char *s;
s = malloc(1024);
strcpy(s, "1234567890");
delchar(s, '5');
```

will not.

To fix, I  would not touch the existing `char *`, but allocate a new one, copying every character, except the one you want to delete from it (note: code isn't tested, but you get the idea).

```
char *delchar(const char *s, char c) {
    char *n, *p = calloc(strlen(s)+1, 1);
    n = p;
    while (*s != '\0') {
       if (*s != c) {
          *n = *s;
          n++;
       }
       s++;
    }
    return p;
}
```

the code is cleaner, easier to read and you are not touching existing strings. Don't forget to `free()` the result of course.

Comment: 1) `char *n = malloc(strlen(s));` --> `char *n = malloc(strlen(s)+1);` 2) There is a need to update the pointer of  destination(use other pointer) and source. 3) need set null-terminator.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY I updated the answer, still the code is untested. It is about the idea behind it.

Comment: Why you thought it was clean without test?

Comment: 1) `n` not top of string. 2) return value can't `free`. 3) not null-terminate.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY it is about the concept of copying instead of messing with an existing string.

Comment: you must replace `code` to `concept`.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY no. I tested it and it works. Using `calloc` now, so null termination is not necessary.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110132/discussion-between-bart-friederichs-and-bluepixy).

Comment: The example causes undefined behavior, so in your case it might work anyway

Comment: Could you elaborate on what is wrong with the code exactly? I think I have fixed everything @BLUEPIXY has mentioned.

Comment: my already pointed out that part isn't fixed yet.

Comment: @BartFriederichs With your current answer you are increasing the variable holding the result of `calloc()` so you never returns it. Freeing latter something else than the result of `calloc()` will lead to a segmentation fault.

Answer (score -1):

The typical algorithm for removing all occurrences of a character from a string would be:

```
void remove_ch (char* restrict dest, const char* restrict src, char ch)
{
  while(*src != '\0')
  {
    if(*src != ch)
    {
      *dest = *src;
      src++;
    }
    dest++;
  }

  *dest = '\0';
}
```

To do in-place deletion, you will have to rewrite this function. Remove `restrict` and also consider using a temporary `char` memory location, since copying between overlapping memory regions could invoke undefined behavior.

Once that modification is done, you should be able to pass the same parameter as both `dest` and `src`.